# How to search for a string in UrlFetchApp.fetch response?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to search for a string in urlfetchapp response using JavaScript indexof but i get error! could you guys tell me what i am doing wrong here and how to look for string in url's source code?

**this is error:**TypeError: Cannot find function indexOf in object

```
var url = "http://www.bbc.com";
var options =
  {
    headers : {'Cache-Control' : 'max-age=0'}
  };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)


if(response.indexOf("sun shine")>-1)
  {
    var myVar="string found";
     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a1').setValue(myVar); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UrlFetchApp.fetch returns an [HTTPResponse object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText()) which doesn't have an indexOf method. 
If you are trying to parse the content of the webpage you could try the following which returns a string and can be searched.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```